# How can i find the cron jobs that run on my site and then move them to the server side?

Tags: plugins, cron, server-load

I am trying to find all the cron jobs on my site and then, move them to the server-side, as my hosting provider gives me the option, to schedule them on the server. I am aware of some plugins like crontrol, but I would also like to know if there is any other alternative.

Also, I am at a starting point on this, so any examples of how I should create the cron job in my server would be also appreciated. (Linux server with the use of Plesk as UI).

Comment: What you’re asking for doesn’t really make sense. The proper way to take advantage of cron on the server is described here: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/hooking-wp-cron-into-the-system-task-scheduler/ You just trigger WordPress’s wp-cron.php periodically. You don’t manually move individual tasks over.

Comment: @JacobPeattie This is the tooltip "Take over wp-cron.php" <WordPress uses its wp-cron.php file for running routine tasks like checking for updates, sending email notifications, and so on. The file is executed every time site visitor loads a page, which can be an issue if there are critical tasks that must run on time. This option will disable the default wp-cron.php execution and provide the means to create a regular scheduled task instead.> So I will have to make a task and add this 0 0 * * * wget --delete-after http://YOUR_SITE_URL/wp-cron.php as the post suggest?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Would it be best to take over the wp-cron.php with this tool, or just add a scheduled task instead? Would it be better to create a function instead? Can I add some exclusions there for specific security tasks like Worfence security check? Or is everything I ask above, have no straight answers and is mostly a trial and error process, so I will have to try and see what fits best my needs?

Comment: There’s nothing to try. Just do what that article says. I’m not really sure what you’re hoping to accomplish that would require anything different.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Ok. I will try the above and will add here as an answer the steps that I followed. Thank you